# Buttons resize with page when i dont want them toWPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hello I added some buttons to my Main_Page.xaml and they resize with the window while running the application and i dont want that. I want them to stay the same proportion when i run the app.

Button names are: Exercise_tab_left_button, Exercise_tab_right_button

```
<Page x:Class="TrackFit_Project.Main_Page"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrackFit_Project"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="453.635" d:DesignWidth="855.207"
  Title="Main_Page"
  ShowsNavigationUI = "false" >

<TabControl Margin="10,10,10.333,10.333">
    <TabItem Header="Exercise"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Width="58"
           Height="22"
           Margin="-2,-2,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <Button x:Name="Exercise_Tab_Profile_Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Click="profileButtonClick">
                <Image>
                    <Image.Source>stock profile image.png</Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Button>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Exercise_tab_rectangle" Fill="#FFCFC6C6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="295" Margin="137,50,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="625"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="234" Margin="169,87,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="548"/>
            **<Button x:Name="Exercise_tab_left_button" Content="&lt;" Margin="148,189,655,154" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button x:Name="Exercise_tab_Right_button" Content="&gt;" Margin="717,189,83,155" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>**
            <TextBlock x:Name="Log_Out_Text_Block" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <Hyperlink x:Name="Log_out_hyperlink" Click="Log_out_hyperlink_Click">Log out</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
</TabControl>
```

[image: This is what i want it to look like][image: This is what i end up getting when i run the app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the properties `Height` and `Width` instead of setting these values indirectly using the `Margin` property.

Currently the `Margin` property determines the width and height of the buttons when they are arranged in the `Grid`. This can be useful when the UI is static and must not resize when the window is resized.

Assuming you want the UI to dynamically adapt to the size you should embed the `Rectangle`, `TextBlock` and the `Button`s in a second `Grid` in a way like this (you might want to figure out the right values for the `Margin` and size of the buttons):

```
<Grid Margin="137,50,10,10">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Exercise_tab_rectangle" Fill="#FFCFC6C6" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="234" Margin="32,37" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button x:Name="Exercise_tab_left_button" Content="&lt;" Margin="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="50" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Button x:Name="Exercise_tab_Right_button" Content="&gt;" Margin="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Height="50" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly and taught me at the same time. very much appreciated!